# Force.com Canvas - modification to third party app required?

Tags: apex, canvas

Can we do this for an *unmodified* existing third party application or do we need customization to the third party app to make it Canvas ready?

Comment: miku can you add some more detail to this question? I't s abit too vague to answer at the moment.

Comment: Originally voted to close, but in retrospect I think the question is clear. "Can a 3th party app be used for canvas without modification?"

Answer (score 3):

If the web app is OAuth2 aware, it may be possible that the only customization that would be required would be to give the third party app a client id/key/secret to the web app (setup time of less than 5 minutes). Advanced uses of canvas, such as manipulating data on a salesforce.com server, will require some customization, and may range from a few hours to dozens of hours of work.

Comment: thanks for replying..i have one question..do we need to host the third party app on heroku server..??Also what if i dont want to host on heroku server..is that possible..??As in salesforce only heroku quick start is available for java and ...

Comment: You can host your app on any server you would like. The Heroku package is simply one of many. Your app could be hosted on Apache, IIS (the most popular servers), or even some other server, so long as it is CGI compliant (meaning, at minimum, it must be able to run server scripting in at least one language). Feel free to leverage whatever platform you feel will best suit you-- even another salesforce.com instance via Sites, or Google Sites (requires Google Code to interface, though), etc.